# How to make a gif never stops in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, ios7, uiwebview, ios8

I have a Gif in a UIWebView, but when the animation ends, it stops. 
How I can do to never stop?

This is my code:

self.video is my UiWebView
my gif is videoGif.gif

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.video.delegate=self;
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"videoGif" ofType:@"gif"];

    NSData *gif = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [self.video loadData:gif MIMEType:@"image/gif" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];

    self.video.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    self.video.scalesPageToFit=YES;
    self.video.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    self.video.scalesPageToFit=YES;
    self.video.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you have access to edit the file? The loop count can be specified within it (using `0` means "loop forever").

Comment: No... but I have already solved it, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can you use UIView Animations. Here i use UIButton for animation. It may be and alternative way. Here my code:

```
NSMutableArray *imageArray=[NSMutableArray new];
for(int i=1;i<=16;i++){
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"win_%d.png",i]]];
}
[animatedButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"win_1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[animatedButton.imageView setAnimationImages:[imageArray copy]];
animatedButton.imageView.animationDuration = .50;
[animatedButton.imageView startAnimating];
```